Sorting algorithm that takes advantage of a new array
I have an array of objects already sorted lexicographicaly by name.
I need to have them sorted by additional criteria as well.
Obviously, I could copy the array and sort it by some other order.
Question is, is there any kind of algorithm that takes advantage of the fact that there is a new, empty array available? Doing sort and copy in one go?
I'm explicitly not asking for in-place algorithms.
As a new thought, wouldn't it be more performant not to create a sorted array but rather a permutation map on the existing array?
I have an array of objects that should be sorted by different criteria, say, as an example, an entry in a phone book could be sorted by family name, be phone number or by residence.
The objective is to reduce the computation time as well as the storage time by taking one go with each of the sorting criteria.

Some (most?) of the usual sorting algorithms can modified so that their first pass copies rather than working in place. Quicksort for example could do it's first partition pass as a copy. Bottom up mergesort, also.  Heapsort can build the heap as a copy. Yada yada.

"Permutation map on the existing array," you mean cycle sort?

@Neil I was not aware of cycle sort, but, no, the objective is to sort a set of objects by many different criteria.First thought was to have many arrays of these objects, but second thought was to have but one array and many permutation maps.

In fact most sorting algorithms work better if you have a new array to copy to rather than forcing them to work in-place.  You haven't studied sorting algorithms enough if you didn't already realize this.

Permutation maps make a mess of cache coherency.  Every access requires a level of indirection both in the sort itself and whatever you use those results for later.

@MarkRansom obviously from your comments, you have experience with sorting and a good eye on performance. Excuse me, the time I learned about sorting algorithms was back in the 80th, and the best thing after researching the net is to ask here ;-) .

What language are you talking about? What advantage are your "permutation maps" supposed to have?

You mean you want to have a primary index and other indices to the same data? "indices can be implemented using a variety of data structures.". Which is more convenient depends highly on your programming language and your requirements; probably some sort of tree.

@Neil not sure we are talking about the same structures. One, I have the primary array of objects of size n. Second, I have an array of integer (or short)  size n where every number i<n occurs just once (a permutation). This gives a different ordering.

On the top level, I think it's just a permutation, how you store it is the details. It's unclear to me, are you maintaining a list, which will be sorted on insertion by different sort criteria, or you are supplied an unordered list and you want to find different sort orders?

It seems that you want to sort an object based on multiple factors, in-place. Many modern languages have in-place sort algorithm and we can use multiple factors simply by passing a function to their sort method.
In Python, for instance, we can use sort() and pass a function as a key (and define ascending or descending):
Python
obj = [
    {'name': 'Alice', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 14, 'factor_4': 22},
    {'name': 'Bob', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 29},
    {'name': 'Charlie', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 21},
    {'name': 'Delta', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 22},
    {'name': 'Emily', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 18, 'factor_4': 23},
    {'name': 'Fox', 'factor_2': 3, 'factor_3': 14, 'factor_4': 24},
    {'name': 'Gabby', 'factor_2': 3, 'factor_3': 19, 'factor_4': 25},
    {'name': 'Hally', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 16, 'factor_4': 27},
]


def sort_by_factors(obj, i, j, k, ia=1, ja=1, ka=1):
    obj.sort(key=lambda obj: (ia * obj[f'factor_{i}'], ja * obj[f'factor_{j}'], ka * obj[f'factor_{k}'], obj['name']))
    return obj


print("\n\nSorted by +factor_4, +factor_2, +factor_3:")
for o in sort_by_factors(obj, 4, 2, 3):
    print(o)


print("\n\nSorted by +factor_2, +factor_4, +factor_3:")
for o in sort_by_factors(obj, 2, 4, 3):
    print(o)


print("\n\nSorted by +factor_3, +factor_2, +factor_4:")
for o in sort_by_factors(obj, 3, 2, 4):
    print(o)

print("\n\nSorted by -factor_4, -factor_2, -factor_3:")
for o in sort_by_factors(obj, 4, 2, 3, -1, -1, -1):
    print(o)

print("\n\nSorted by -factor_2, -factor_4, -factor_3:")
for o in sort_by_factors(obj, 2, 4, 3, -1, -1, -1):
    print(o)

print("\n\nSorted by -factor_3, -factor_2, -factor_4:")
for o in sort_by_factors(obj, 3, 2, 4, -1, -1, -1):
    print(o)

print("\n\nSorted by -factor_4, +factor_2, -factor_3:")
for o in sort_by_factors(obj, 4, 2, 3, -1, 1, -1):
    print(o)

print("\n\nSorted by +factor_2, -factor_4, -factor_3:")
for o in sort_by_factors(obj, 2, 4, 3, 1, -1, -1):
    print(o)


print("\n\nSorted by +factor_3, +factor_2, -factor_4:")
for o in sort_by_factors(obj, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, -1):
    print(o)



Prints


Sorted by +factor_4, +factor_2, +factor_3:
{'name': 'Charlie', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 21}
{'name': 'Delta', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 22}
{'name': 'Alice', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 14, 'factor_4': 22}
{'name': 'Emily', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 18, 'factor_4': 23}
{'name': 'Fox', 'factor_2': 3, 'factor_3': 14, 'factor_4': 24}
{'name': 'Gabby', 'factor_2': 3, 'factor_3': 19, 'factor_4': 25}
{'name': 'Hally', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 16, 'factor_4': 27}
{'name': 'Bob', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 29}


Sorted by +factor_2, +factor_4, +factor_3:
{'name': 'Delta', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 22}
{'name': 'Emily', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 18, 'factor_4': 23}
{'name': 'Bob', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 29}
{'name': 'Charlie', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 21}
{'name': 'Alice', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 14, 'factor_4': 22}
{'name': 'Hally', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 16, 'factor_4': 27}
{'name': 'Fox', 'factor_2': 3, 'factor_3': 14, 'factor_4': 24}
{'name': 'Gabby', 'factor_2': 3, 'factor_3': 19, 'factor_4': 25}


Sorted by +factor_3, +factor_2, +factor_4:
{'name': 'Alice', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 14, 'factor_4': 22}
{'name': 'Fox', 'factor_2': 3, 'factor_3': 14, 'factor_4': 24}
{'name': 'Delta', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 22}
{'name': 'Bob', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 29}
{'name': 'Charlie', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 21}
{'name': 'Hally', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 16, 'factor_4': 27}
{'name': 'Emily', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 18, 'factor_4': 23}
{'name': 'Gabby', 'factor_2': 3, 'factor_3': 19, 'factor_4': 25}


Sorted by -factor_4, -factor_2, -factor_3:
{'name': 'Bob', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 29}
{'name': 'Hally', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 16, 'factor_4': 27}
{'name': 'Gabby', 'factor_2': 3, 'factor_3': 19, 'factor_4': 25}
{'name': 'Fox', 'factor_2': 3, 'factor_3': 14, 'factor_4': 24}
{'name': 'Emily', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 18, 'factor_4': 23}
{'name': 'Alice', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 14, 'factor_4': 22}
{'name': 'Delta', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 22}
{'name': 'Charlie', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 21}


Sorted by -factor_2, -factor_4, -factor_3:
{'name': 'Gabby', 'factor_2': 3, 'factor_3': 19, 'factor_4': 25}
{'name': 'Fox', 'factor_2': 3, 'factor_3': 14, 'factor_4': 24}
{'name': 'Hally', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 16, 'factor_4': 27}
{'name': 'Alice', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 14, 'factor_4': 22}
{'name': 'Charlie', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 21}
{'name': 'Bob', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 29}
{'name': 'Emily', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 18, 'factor_4': 23}
{'name': 'Delta', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 22}


Sorted by -factor_3, -factor_2, -factor_4:
{'name': 'Gabby', 'factor_2': 3, 'factor_3': 19, 'factor_4': 25}
{'name': 'Emily', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 18, 'factor_4': 23}
{'name': 'Hally', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 16, 'factor_4': 27}
{'name': 'Charlie', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 21}
{'name': 'Bob', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 29}
{'name': 'Delta', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 22}
{'name': 'Fox', 'factor_2': 3, 'factor_3': 14, 'factor_4': 24}
{'name': 'Alice', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 14, 'factor_4': 22}


Sorted by -factor_4, +factor_2, -factor_3:
{'name': 'Bob', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 29}
{'name': 'Hally', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 16, 'factor_4': 27}
{'name': 'Gabby', 'factor_2': 3, 'factor_3': 19, 'factor_4': 25}
{'name': 'Fox', 'factor_2': 3, 'factor_3': 14, 'factor_4': 24}
{'name': 'Emily', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 18, 'factor_4': 23}
{'name': 'Delta', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 22}
{'name': 'Alice', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 14, 'factor_4': 22}
{'name': 'Charlie', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 21}


Sorted by +factor_2, -factor_4, -factor_3:
{'name': 'Bob', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 29}
{'name': 'Emily', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 18, 'factor_4': 23}
{'name': 'Delta', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 22}
{'name': 'Hally', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 16, 'factor_4': 27}
{'name': 'Alice', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 14, 'factor_4': 22}
{'name': 'Charlie', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 21}
{'name': 'Gabby', 'factor_2': 3, 'factor_3': 19, 'factor_4': 25}
{'name': 'Fox', 'factor_2': 3, 'factor_3': 14, 'factor_4': 24}


Sorted by +factor_3, +factor_2, -factor_4:
{'name': 'Alice', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 14, 'factor_4': 22}
{'name': 'Fox', 'factor_2': 3, 'factor_3': 14, 'factor_4': 24}
{'name': 'Bob', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 29}
{'name': 'Delta', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 22}
{'name': 'Charlie', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 15, 'factor_4': 21}
{'name': 'Hally', 'factor_2': 2, 'factor_3': 16, 'factor_4': 27}
{'name': 'Emily', 'factor_2': 1, 'factor_3': 18, 'factor_4': 23}
{'name': 'Gabby', 'factor_2': 3, 'factor_3': 19, 'factor_4': 25}


C++
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>

struct Object
{
    std::string name;
    int factor_2, factor_3, factor_4;
};

static const bool compare(const Object &a, const Object &b)
{
    return std::tie(a.factor_4, a.factor_2, a.factor_3, a.name) < std::tie(b.factor_4, b.factor_2, b.factor_3, b.name);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Object> obj = {
        {"Alice", 2, 14, 22},
        {"Bob", 1, 15, 29},
        {"Charlie", 2, 15, 21},
    };

    std::sort(obj.begin(), obj.end(), compare);

    for (const auto &obj : obj)
    {
        std::cout << obj.name << " ";
    }
}


Prints
Charlie Alice Bob
Java
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> objects = new ArrayList<>();
        objects.add(Map.of("name", "Alice", "factor_2", 2, "factor_3", 14, "factor_4", 22));
        objects.add(Map.of("name", "Bob", "factor_2", 1, "factor_3", 15, "factor_4", 29));
        objects.add(Map.of("name", "Charlie", "factor_2", 2, "factor_3", 15, "factor_4", 21));
        // ... other objects

        sortByFactors(objects, 4, 2, 3);
        System.out.println(objects);
    }

    public static void sortByFactors(List<Map<String, Object>> objects, int i, int j, int k) {
        objects.sort(Comparator.comparing((Map<String, Object> o) -> (Integer) o.get("factor_" + i))
                .thenComparing(o -> (Integer) o.get("factor_" + j))
                .thenComparing(o -> (Integer) o.get("factor_" + k))
                .thenComparing(o -> (String) o.get("name")));
    }
}


Prints
[{name=Charlie, factor_3=15, factor_4=21, factor_2=2}, {name=Alice, factor_3=14, factor_4=22, factor_2=2}, {name=Bob, factor_3=15, factor_4=29, factor_2=1}]

JavaScript


const obj = [
  { name: "Alice", factor_2: 2, factor_3: 14, factor_4: 22 },
  { name: "Bob", factor_2: 1, factor_3: 15, factor_4: 29 },
  { name: "Charlie", factor_2: 2, factor_3: 15, factor_4: 21 },
  { name: "Delta", factor_2: 1, factor_3: 15, factor_4: 22 },
  { name: "Emily", factor_2: 1, factor_3: 18, factor_4: 23 },
  { name: "Fox", factor_2: 3, factor_3: 14, factor_4: 24 },
  { name: "Gabby", factor_2: 3, factor_3: 19, factor_4: 25 },
  { name: "Hally", factor_2: 2, factor_3: 16, factor_4: 27 },
];

function sortByFactors(array, i, j, k, ia = 1, ja = 1, ka = 1) {
  array.sort((a, b) => {
    return (
      ia * a[`factor_${i}`] - ia * b[`factor_${i}`] ||
      ja * a[`factor_${j}`] - ja * b[`factor_${j}`] ||
      ka * a[`factor_${k}`] - ka * b[`factor_${k}`] ||
      a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
    );
  });
  return array;
}

console.log("Sorted by +factor_4, +factor_2, +factor_3:");
console.log(sortByFactors(obj, 4, 2, 3));



Prints
Press "Run code snippet" button above to see
Sorted by +factor_4, +factor_2, +factor_3:
[
  { name: 'Charlie', factor_2: 2, factor_3: 15, factor_4: 21 },
  { name: 'Delta', factor_2: 1, factor_3: 15, factor_4: 22 },
  { name: 'Alice', factor_2: 2, factor_3: 14, factor_4: 22 },
  { name: 'Emily', factor_2: 1, factor_3: 18, factor_4: 23 },
  { name: 'Fox', factor_2: 3, factor_3: 14, factor_4: 24 },
  { name: 'Gabby', factor_2: 3, factor_3: 19, factor_4: 25 },
  { name: 'Hally', factor_2: 2, factor_3: 16, factor_4: 27 },
  { name: 'Bob', factor_2: 1, factor_3: 15, factor_4: 29 }

Note:
"Many sorting algorithms rearrange arrays into sorted order in-place, including: bubble sort, comb sort, selection sort, insertion sort, heapsort, and Shell sort." See here

Sort by creating a new copy
In case, you are interested in creating a new copy, then just create a new copy. In python, sorted() and in Java Stream.sorted() automatically create a copy of the object. In some languages that do not have such methods, we could simply create a copy.

I don't think that's it. OP may have been a bit vague, but I believe the goal was essentially the opposite: to not sort in-place but to sort-while-copying

@user555045 I agree. A bit unclear. You're probably right. Yet, that's also possible. In python sorted() does that for instance. Stream.sorted() in Java.
